# Woocommerce replace Storefront header with Elementor header

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, storefront, elementor

I am pulling my hair out trying to replace the default StoreFront Theme header with a custom header created using Elementor (using a shortcode). However, my code only seems to replace the default nav buttons with blank spaces.

Any ideas on what I am mising?

**My code:**

```
add_action('init', 'replace_header' );

function replace_header(){
    remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_primary_navigation', 'storefront_before_site', 'storefront_before_header', 50 );
    add_action('storefront_header', 'my_custom_header', 50);
}
function my_custom_header(){
    do_shortcode('[elementor-template id="59"]')
}
```

**Here is the default Storefront header.php file:**

```
    <?php
/**
 * The header for our theme.
 *
 * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div id="content">
 *
 * @package storefront
 */

?><!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">

<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

<?php do_action( 'storefront_before_site' ); ?>

<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
    <?php do_action( 'storefront_before_header' ); ?>

    <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner" style="<?php storefront_header_styles(); ?>">
        <div class="col-full">

            <?php
            /**
             * Functions hooked into storefront_header action
             *
             * @hooked storefront_skip_links                       - 0
             * @hooked storefront_social_icons                     - 10
             * @hooked storefront_site_branding                    - 20
             * @hooked storefront_secondary_navigation             - 30
             * @hooked storefront_product_search                   - 40
             * @hooked storefront_primary_navigation_wrapper       - 42
             * @hooked storefront_primary_navigation               - 50
             * @hooked storefront_header_cart                      - 60
             * @hooked storefront_primary_navigation_wrapper_close - 68
             */
            do_action( 'storefront_header' ); ?>

        </div>
    </header><!-- #masthead -->

    <?php
    /**
     * Functions hooked in to storefront_before_content
     *
     * @hooked storefront_header_widget_region - 10
     */
    do_action( 'storefront_before_content' ); ?>

    <div id="content" class="site-content" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="col-full">

        <?php
        /**
         * Functions hooked in to storefront_content_top
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 10
         */
        do_action( 'storefront_content_top' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted. This PHP function set worked.

```
    //Delete primary navigation
add_action('init', 'delete_navigation' );

function delete_navigation(){
    remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_primary_navigation',    50 );
}

//Delete header cart
add_action('init', 'delete_cart' );

function delete_cart(){
    remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_header_cart',   60 );
}

//Delete navigation wrapper close
add_action('init', 'delete_wrapper' );

function delete_wrapper(){
    remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_primary_navigation_wrapper_close',   68 );
}
```